# How to index a system using python

Tags: python, indexing, tokenize, information-retrieval

I have a project where I need to create an information retrieval system for a set of documents. The first step is indexing(lemmatization, tokenization , stoplist, etc.). Now the problem is I seem to be having trouble with passing my documents to the code.
Here is the code:

```
import os
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

# Step 2: Collect the dataset
folder_path = documents
docs = []
for file_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
    with open(os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)) as f:
        docs.append(f.read())

# Step 3: Indexing
nltk.download('stopwords')
nltk.download('wordnet')
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

def tokenize_and_lemmatize(text):
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower())
    tokens = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(token) for token in tokens if token.isalpha()]
    tokens = [token for token in tokens if token not in stop_words]
    return tokens

# Step 4: Tf-idf retrieval model
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize_and_lemmatize)
tfidf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(docs)

# Step 5: Query
query = "machine learning"
query_vec = vectorizer.transform([query])

# Step 6: Similarity measure
similarity_scores = cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix, query_vec)

# Step 7: Display results
results = [(score, doc) for score, doc in zip(similarity_scores, docs)]
results = sorted(results, reverse=True)

for score, doc in results:
    print(f"{score[0]:.3f}: {doc[:50]}")
```

and here is the output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-e60067741079> in <cell line: 11>()
      9 folder_path = documents
     10 docs = []
---> 11 for file_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
     12     with open(os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)) as f:
     13         docs.append(f.read())

TypeError: listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike, integer or None, not list
```

I tried multiple ways for passing the documents but im not fluent in python so Im having trouble understanding the codes.

Comment: I don't see where you define the variable "documents". But it sounds like "documents" is a list. It should be the path to the folder, e.g. ```documents = "/paths/to/documents"``` vs ```documents = ["doc1", "doc2"]```.

Comment: I defined documents in another segment of code like this:                               
   documents = glob.glob(f"{'/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/documents'}/*.txt")   . this works perfectly fine

Comment: glob returns a list if I remember correctly, so you are trying to call `os.listdir()` on a list. Instead you should be looping through the files listed in documents and opening them directly.